# Theme with tpl.php

Tags: theming

I am trying to theme a data table with a tpl.php file.
I am placing the theme-table.tpl.php file in the project.
How do I call it to theme from within the code?
The file contains html and php prints.

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the [Theming Guide](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme)?

Comment: Apparently not. I used go through the whole guide just to find this one? Thanks for the link :-)

Comment: Nah, no need to read it all but it's a good resource if you're new to theming. The [`hook_theme()` docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) are pretty helpful too if you haven't come across them before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mymodule.module, you should first declare a theme:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_theme.
 */
function my_module_theme() {
  return array(
    'my_module_page' => array(
        'variables' => array('mydata'=>"Default value"),
        'template' => 'my_module_page',
     ),
  );
}
```

The value of template is the filename of your tpl.php file.

You can use the variables array to pass data to the template, just like I will be doing here with mydata.

Then, in any function of your module, you can create a renderable array, render it using `drupal_render` and output it, or print it, depending on your needs.

```
$renderable = array(
  '#theme' => 'my_module_page',
  '#mydata' => "Hello World!",
);

return drupal_render($renderable);
```

So, your template (my_module_page.tpl.php) should look like:

```html
Here is my template data : <?php echo $mydata ?>
```